# how to change int to date in dax?

Tags: powerbi, ssas, ssas-tabular

I am consuming LIVE from an SSAS cube.

I have my Fact table with the below column:
[image]

When I display it in a matrix visual, in my pbix I get this:

[image]

But in SSAS I see it as:

[image]

How can I display it in a nice dd-MMMM-yyyy format?

Ps: the table comes from a ‘sql server’ source with INT data type.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using a Live Connection to SSAS, this has to be done in the Analysis Services model.  The only model changes you can make in that case is to add measures.

This column should have a relationship to a Date dimension which has a Date type column as well as other datetime hierarchy columns like Month, Quarter, and Year.